# How to update item in sql if a variable isn't empty?

Tags: php, sql

I'm getting variable from parser.

If variable $desc is empty - my request just stops, but I need just pass it.

It's my part of code.

```
$desc = $description->plaintext;
if(!empty($desc)) {
    $query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = 'blabla' WHERE remote_id = '" . $dataId . "';";
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = 'EMPTY' WHERE remote_id = '" . $dataId . "';";
}
$sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

But if(!empty($desc)) doesn't work

Comment: use if($desc !="") { }

Comment: what is the value for `$description->plaintext` ?

Comment: @JYoThI, it's not working(

Comment: @SachinPATIL, because I'm using simple html dom and in $description->plaintext I have this value find('.description div p')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$desc = $description->plaintext;
if(count($desc)>0) {
     $query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = 'blabla' WHERE  remote_id = '" . $dataId . "';";
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = 'EMPTY' WHERE remote_id = '" . $dataId . "';";
}
$sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Comment: echo $desc. maybe it is not null

Comment: it's null. If I use print_r($desc). I'll get array => 0

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure $desc is empty, mind you a space or newline character will not make it empty. Check the value by debugging or by var_dump(). If there is space or newline you can use trim().

```
$desc = trim($description->plaintext);
if(!empty($desc)) {
$query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = 'blabla' WHERE remote_id = '" . $dataId . "';";
} else {
$query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = 'EMPTY' WHERE remote_id = '" . $dataId . "';";
}
$sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```